# Manually closing Activity leaves transparent window

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a problem and I found nothing in my searches that's solving it.
My activity should close, when the user presses the `Ok-/Cancel-Button` of a created `AlertDialog`.
When the activity is closing, there is a transparent overlay remaining. How can  I let it disappear?

I tried it with `System.exit(0) and finish()`, both with the same result.
How can I close the activity without any remains?

Thanks very much for you help!

Comment: Are you using dismiss() API of dialog when ok/cancel button is pressed ?

Comment: I never saw that. Can you post your code around your AlertDialog.Builder ?

Comment: Thanks also to sat for the hint!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're closing the activity and the dialog is being left behind.

Call `dialog.dismiss()` or `dialog.cancel()` on the `DialogInterface.OnClickListener` and then call `finish()` and see what happens. But really, we need some code.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem. Just forgot to close the dialog. And the finish() comand was obviously at the wrong position. Thanks for helping! And sorry for forgetting the code. :)